# Delete a variable number of lines in a Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word, docx

BACKGROUND: My daughter works as a Special Needs instructor for a very large school district (with overwhelmed IT especially at the start of the new school year) and has an untouchable/unreachable database that creates a pdf report. She and many of her ~50 Special Needs Instructor co-workers want summary reports that hold only data applicable to their respective needs (1 page) instead of multiple pages (2-6 pages). She alone has over 75 reports of this type.

THUS FAR: On a PC running Windows 10 with Office 365, I've manually converted a pdf file to MS Word and modified a *stack overflow obtained* VBA macro to delete everything after "Delete Hereafter".

**THE NEEDS: From a list of file names in an Office document, open the PDFs as DOCm files and save, then modify each DOCm file and save.**

**THE SOUGHT-AFTER MODIFICATION:** Each report has two tables with text between. The second table always begins with the same header: "Second Table Title". **For the second table, she wants to delete rows 2 through *a row which always contains "Text Needed" less 1***, a variable number of rows.

Your assistance would be appreciated not only by her, but by her co-workers as well. I am a novice user who has benefitted from Stack Overflow answers many times, but need a bit more help to solve this problem.

Comment: It would improve your question (and your odds of getting a helpful answer) if you [edit]ed it to include a [mcve]. Basically, include a sample document and the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub TableCleaner()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, r As Long
With ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .MatchCase = True
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Text = "Text Needed"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Execute
    End With
    If .Find.Found = True Then i = .Cells(1).RowIndex - 1
  End With
  For r = i To 2 Step -1
    .Rows(r).Delete
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```